# How to pass parameteres to get_queryset method of django models manager?

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I am trying to follow this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/managers/). I would like to pass somehow parameters to get_queryset, but don't know how. Not working demo below.

```
class ContextAwareNotificationsManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self, user):
        return super(ContextAwareNotificationsManager, self).get_queryset(user).filter((
            Q(kind='SYSTEM') | Q(kind='TODO', status=False)
        ), content_type__name__in=['publisher', 'site', 'channel']).order_by('-date')
```

Comment: @petkostas's answer is the way to go, you should generally avoid overriding `get_query_set` and instead add your own methods that give you the queryset you're looking for.

Comment: @Matt: These days, overriding `get_queryset` does seem like the proper thing to do, generally, according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset). Just maybe not in this specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
class ContextAwareNotificationsManager(models.Manager):

    def filter_user(self, user):
        return super(ContextAwareNotificationsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(...)
```